# mysql_real_escape_string not being used with given regex

Tags: php, mysql-real-escape-string

I am using a dataHandler library to handle all of my db inserts / updates, etc.
The library has the following functions:

```
function prepareValue($value, $connection){
$preparedValue = $value;
if(is_null($value)){
    $preparedValue = 'NULL';
}
else{
    $preparedValue = '\''.mysql_real_escape_string($value, $connection).'\'';
}
return $preparedValue;
}

function parseParams($params, $type, $connection){
$fields = "";
$values = "";

    if ($type == "UPDATE"){
    $return = "";
    foreach ($params as $key => $value){
    if ($return == ""){
        if (preg_match("/\)$/", $value)){
            $return = $key."=".$value;
        }
        else{
            $return = $key."=".$this->prepareValue($value, $connection);
        }
    }
    else{
        if (preg_match("/\)$/", $value)){
            $return = $return.", ".$key."=".$value;
        }
        else{
            $return = $return.", ".$key."=".$this->prepareValue($value,              
                         $connection);
        }
    }
    }
    return $return;
/* rest of function contains similar but for "INSERT", etc.
   }
```

These functions are then used to build queries using sprintf, as in:

```
$query = sprintf("UPDATE table SET " .
    $this->parseParams($params, "UPDATE", $conn) .
" WHERE fieldValue = %s;", $this->prepareValue($thesis_id, $conn));
```

`$params` is an associative array:  `array("db_field_name"=>$value, "db_field_name2"=>$value2, etc.)`

I am now running into problems when I want to do an update or insert of a string that ends in ")" because the parseParams function does not put these values in quotes.

My question is this:
Why would this library NOT call prepareValue on strings that end in a closed parenthesis?  Would calling `mysql_real_escape_string()` on this value cause any problems?  I could easily modify the library, but I am assuming there is a reason the author handled this particular regex this way.  I just can't figure out what that reason is!  And I'm hesitant to make any modifications until I understand the reasoning behind what is here.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I cannot see _any_ reason why you would not call `mysql_real_escape_string()` on a value ending in `)`.  What is this library? Perhaps the author had only some unusual personal use case in mind.

Comment: @Michael  Thanks for the sanity check.  As far as I know it's just a general use library that the author had for database interactions, and wasn't designed for any special use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note that inside `prepareValue` not only `mysql_real_escape_string` is applied to the value but it is also put inside `'`. With this in mind, we could suspect that author assumed all strings ending with `)` to be mysql function calls, ie:

```
$params = array(
    'field1' => "John Doe",
    'field2' => "CONCAT('John',' ','Doe')",
    'field3' => "NOW()"
);
```

Thats the only reasonable answer that comes to mind.

Comment: Thank you!  That makes a lot of sense, and for my purposes means I can edit away as I am not passing in any function calls.